# JVM benchmarking application

Tags: java, jvm, benchmarking

We want to compare general performance (CPU, I/O, network, ...) of different JVMs for the same Java version (1.5) in different environments (Windows, Solaris, ...).

Do you know of any JVM benchmarking application which can be used to compare results from different JVMs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just wanted a little more human feedback from people who have used them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up using [SPECjvm2008](http://www.spec.org/jvm2008/) as we needed something more 'standard' than 'rigorous'.

The goal was to quickly compare performance between different JVM environments and show it to systems group. SPECjvm2008 was quite easy to setup and served well to the task.

Answer (score 1):

[The Java Grande Forum Benchmark Suite](http://www2.epcc.ed.ac.uk/computing/research_activities/java_grande/index_1.html) seems a little outdated, but it's the only one I found which speaks about I/O and network bandwith.

Comment: The link is now broken.